# Java's getServletContext() equivalent in regular Java class?

Tags: java, servlets, path, relative-path

Basically I'm trying to point to a properties file in the WEB-INF folder, which is easy enough when I'm actually using a servlet, but I have a couple normal Java classes which I need to point to the same "relative" path and I can't seem to figure out any way to do it.

Normally this is how I point to the file:

```
InputStream in = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/prop.properties");
```

Comment: Maybe `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()`?

Comment: Just tried it. Doesn't seem to work either. "in" still contains null. I checked what `getClass().getClassLoader()` contains and it's `"WebappClassLoader
   context: /IncTest
   delegate: false
   repositories:
     /WEB-INF/classes/
 ----------> Parent Classloader:
 org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@181a7dc
 "` Dunno if that helps.

Comment: Wait a minute -- so you **are** using a servlet? I'm confused now as to your requirements. Your classloader is a `WebAppClassLoader` inside Tomcat.

Comment: No, this is just a regular Java class that's part of a WebApp, which is being used as some automated back-end maintenance work.

Comment: In that case I find @axtavt's advice very good. Anything else would amount to just hackery. I thought you needed to execute code from your WAR outside of a servlet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know the only way to do it is to pass `ServletContext` into these classes (perhaps wrapped into some other class, to separate different levels of abstraction).

Since you have a web application, all object graphs should originate from the roots where `ServletContext` is available (servlets, filters, listeners, etc), so that you can pass `ServletContext` along the graph from these roots.

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply. I used your idea and it works fine. Thanks!